# linq help to exclude null items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack

I have the linq expression below that derives all the email tags on a web page. However it also seems to be catching empty anchor **missing href attributes**

items and throwing a null reference exception error:

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}

```
> var emailNodes =
> _htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
>                           .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
>                           .Where(href => href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // keep emails, skipp links
>                           .ToList();
```

Is there an adjustment available to the LINQ that would exclude the empty values outright?

> EDIT: as noted, the error is seem when the html is lacking the href
>   all together. is there a way to handle for this in LINQ?**

Comment: if you use `StartsWith`, why should it select null items?

Comment: Are you sure a.Atrributes["href"] isn't null? I would suggest doing a null check before getting Value from this. You always want to have null checks before trying to access values within a linq statement

Comment: Can you include the stack trace so we can see exactly where that error is originating from?

Comment: wait. if `href` is empty then `StartsWith` will return false. i guess your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You're already selecting `//a[@href]` which should exclude anything without an href attribute. It doesnt exclude empty *value* for the attribute but the answer given does that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a tags without href then check for null or empty href string before using the dot operator.

```
var emailNodes =
    _htmlDocument.Value.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                 .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"] != null)
                 .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
                 .Where(href => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(href) && href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // keep emails, skipp links
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: can it also be made smart enough to exclude a tags without href attributes? i am now getting null error for these items too that were previously covered by the other failure?

Comment: You should be able to add another layer after SelectNodes and before Select:  .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"] != null)  This should prevent the following select .Value from accessing on null.

Comment: See my edit adding this line: .Where(a => a.Attributes["href"] != null).